# .htaccess and RewriteCond not working on NGINX

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

After installing Nginx admin nginxcp.com

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.22\.111\.22
```

.htaccess not work

Where can any IP download File

server.domain.com/files/4/u9lv1n7c0mxk1m/10MBtest.zip

Not seen IP in .htaccess , and file downloading, from any IP

ex:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^176\.67\.116\.49
RewriteRule ^.*$ "domain.com/404.html?domain.com/ur1v4wrhjzu9/1.rar.html"
```

How can I used `.htaccess` files in NGINX?

Answer (score 0):

NGINX doesn't support `.htaccess` files, that is an Apache feature. Try [this site (not tested by me YMMV)](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess). If you want to use .htaccess files you will need to install Apache which is a web server using a different (heavier) architecture.

Comment: But nginx admin just does proxy to apache

Presumably , .htaccess work with nginx

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($remote_addr !~ '^176\.67\.116\.49') {
    return http://domain.com/404.html?url=$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately did not succeed

Another solution?

Comment: This code is for nginx.conf. It's not clear what URL is needed for the redirect to the 404 page.

Comment: Will not succeed in nginx configuration ... Because the IP variable per visitor ... And each visitor a special folder and .htaccess special

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name download.example.com;
  allow 111.222.333.444;
  deny all;
  error_page 403 = @redirect;
  location @redirect {
    return 301 http://path/to/redirect;
  }
  location / {
    # handle passing ip
  }
}
```

Comment: Where to put this ? ..

Will not succeed in nginx configuration ...

Because the IP variable per visitor ...

And each visitor a special folder and .htaccess special